# Generating uniform distribution using Math.random()

Tags: javascript, node.js, random

In the [MDN Math.random](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) web page the comment for the example function `getRandomInt(..)` says that `Math.round()` was not used since it gives non-uniform distribution, **which implies using Math.floor(..) will produce uniform distribution**.

```
// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
```

However, the following code shows that the frequency of generating a random number is directly proportional to the value of the number. i.e Higher the value of the number, higher the frequency. This behaviour is same on **nodejs and on firefox browser**.

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random


// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var data = {};
var a;
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
  a = getRandomInt(1, 50);

  if (typeof data[a] === 'undefined') { // first time initialize
    data[a] = a;
  } else {
    data[a] = data[a] + a;
  }
}

//console.log(data);
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

So with this property of Math.random() how to generate a uniform distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You increment your counter using `a`. The result of the counter would be `a*<actual frequency>`.

If you increment with `1`, you will see that it actually has a uniform distribution.

```
if (typeof data[a] === 'undefined') { // first time initialize
    data[a] = 1;
} else {
    data[a] = data[a] + 1;
}
```

```js
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random


// Returns a random integer between min (included) and max (excluded)
// Using Math.round() will give you a non-uniform distribution!
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

var data = {};
var a;
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
{
    a = getRandomInt(1,50);

    if (typeof data[a] === 'undefined') { // first time initialize
    data[a] = 1;
    } else {
    data[a] = data[a] + 1;
    }
}
//console.log(data);
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="json"></pre>
```