# Generating a random number within a large range based on probabilities

Tags: javascript, math, probability

I am curious how Stake.com managed to create the game "Limbo" where the odds of a multiplier happening is specific to the probability they've calculated. Here's the game : https://stake.com/casino/games/limbo

For example :
Multiplier -> x2
Probability -> 49.5% chance.

What it means is you have a 49.5% chance of winning because those are the odds that the multiplier will actually hit a number above x2.

If you set the multiplier all the way up to x1,000,000. You have a 0.00099% chance of actually hitting 1,000,000.

It's not a project I'm working on but I'm just extremely curious how we could achieve this.
Example:

```
Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000)
```

is not as random as we think, since Math.random() generates a number between 0-1. When paired with a huge multiplier like 1,000,000. We would actually generate a 6-figure number most of the time and it's not as random as we thought.

I've read that we have to convert it into a power law distribution but I'm not sure how it works. Would love to have more material to read up on how it works.

Comment: To achieve 49.5% of winning, you could generate a number between 0 and 1000 like `Math.floor(Math.random()*1000)`, then if the result is less than 495, this would be a win, and a loss otherwise.

Comment: Except your multipliers will consistently be 3-figures around 100-999, and that would give you a more than 50% chance of landing more than x2. I don't think that's right.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how `Math.random()`, but the premise is for it to generate observations from a uniform probability distribution. If this is the case, this method should work fine. You can check [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26795084/generating-uniform-distribution-using-math-random).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to define some function that gives the probability of winning for a given multiplier N. These probabilities don't have to add up to 1, because they are not part of the same random variable; there is a unique random variable for each N chosen and two events, win or lose; we can subscript them as win(N) and lose(N). We really only need to define win(N) since lose(N) = 1 - win(N).

Something like an exponential functional would make sense here. Consider win(N) = 2^(1 - N). Then we get the following probabilities of winning:

```
n    win(n)
1    1
2    1/2
3    1/4
4    1/8
etc
```

Or we could use just an inverse function: win(N) = 1/N

```
n    win(n)
1    1
2    1/2
3    1/3
...
```

Then to actually see whether you win or lose for a given N, just choose a random number in some range - [0.0, 1.0) works fine for this purpose - and see whether that number is less than the win(N). If so, it's a win, of not, it's a loss.

Yes, technically speaking, it is probably true that the floating point numbers are not really uniformly distributed over [0, 1) when calling standard library functions. If you really need that level of precision then you have a much harder problem. But, for a game, regular rand() type functions should be plenty uniform for your purposes.

Comment: This is very useful for a smaller range where n <= 100 since most of the time Math.random would generate numbers from 0.01 to 0.99, for cases of probability that needs n reach up to numbers as high as 1,000,000, I've laid out a flow chart over excel to visualise the probability over these odds. One way to do this is to consistently loop over Math.random() and if Math.random < 0.5, then return a multiplier of 1 and above. if it's >0.5, we will generate a number that will be a minimum of multiplier 2 and above. This loops repeatedly so the probability to get Math.random > 0.5 in a row is lower